# Install flutter application on IPhone, without developer account

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

I recently started developing apps on flutter for iPhone. The task is to make an application that will be on my father's phone (he has an iPhone), which, if necessary, can be updated (there will be no physical access to the device, since I am in another city).
The application itself has already been made and installed on my device during debugging in release mode.
Questions:

1. How long will an application installed in this way live (I read somewhere that they live for several days, after which they need to be updated)?
2. How do I install the app on an iOS device so that it works there without having to reinstall (without a developer account)?
3. Is it possible to install apps by link or downloaded on iOS without hacking, without a developer account and without access to mackbook (my father only has a phone, and I live in another city)?
   Thank you!

Comment: If you have a free developer account then you can install to a single device it will run for (I believe) 7 days before it needs to be re-installed by physically connecting the phone to your Mac. If you have a paid account then you can use TestFlight to provide builds that are valid for 90 days and can be installed "over the air"

Comment: That is, without publishing in the AppStore, the application will not be able to work for a long time?

Comment: Well, you can continue to publish to TestFlight but never actually release it, but you will need to update every 90 days.  But with a free membership, no you can't have an app working for more than a few days.

Comment: Is it possible to publish in TestFlight without a paid account?

Comment: No. TestFlight is a paid account feature